# Using IIS Rewrite to add HttpOnly Flag To Cookies Not Working

Tags: iis, cookies, url-rewriting, httponly

I found numerous examples of adding the HttpOnly to my cookies but it does not work for me and I am not sure why. All the examples I found were the same and I copied this one from one of the posts that I had found. I am using .NET 3.5 under IIS 7.0. Hopefully someone can tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks

```xml
<rewrite>
  <outboundRules>
    <rule name="Add HttpOnly" preCondition="No HttpOnly">
      <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Set_Cookie" pattern=".*" negate="false" />
      <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:0}; HttpOnly" />
      <conditions>
      </conditions>
    </rule>
    <preConditions>
      <preCondition name="No HttpOnly">
        <add input="{RESPONSE_Set_Cookie}" pattern="." />
        <add input="{RESPONSE_Set_Cookie}" pattern="; HttpOnly" negate="true" />
      </preCondition>
    </preConditions>
  </outboundRules>
</rewrite>
```

**UPDATE**

I figured out how to turn on tracing and found that the preCondition is looking at all the cookies as a whole instead of each individual cookie.

So instead of evaluating

```
Set-Cookie: myC5=we have S Cookie; path=/; secure
Set-Cookie: myC6=we have S Cookie; path=/; secure
Set-Cookie: myC7=we have S Cookie; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
```

It is evaluating

```
myC5=we have S Cookie; path=/; secure,myC6=we have S Cookie; path=/; secure,myC7=we have S Cookie; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
```

Since the whole string has ; HttpOnly in it, the preCondition fails.

How do I get past this? Any ideas?

Comment: It's perfectly acceptable to [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question) you know?

Answer (score 27):

I finally got pass this so I wanted to post for others that might run into this. I removed my preConditions and just used conditions. I then had to use the back reference to get to the single cookie.

```xml
    <rewrite>
        <outboundRules>
            <rule name="Add HttpOnly">
                <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Set_Cookie" pattern=".+" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{R:0}" pattern="; HttpOnly" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:0}; HttpOnly" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Add Secure">
                <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Set_Cookie" pattern=".+" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{R:0}" pattern="; Secure" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:0}; Secure" />
            </rule>
        </outboundRules>
    </rewrite>
```

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: Added answer as OP seems to no longer be active on SO, made wiki

Comment: Tested on IIS 7.5 Server 2008 R2 ASP Classic works fine. Many other examples seemed to be close but this answer works as it should.

Comment: I think the pattern in the match section needs to be ".+" instead of ".*" - otherwise, empty cookies are created on pages that aren't setting cookies.

Comment: This saved my from hitting my head against the wall. Cheers!